# How does this C SHA1 implementation makes use of its parameter?

Tags: c, sha

I thought that only password and salt can influence the output of SHA1. However, I found that if I change `correct_hash`, the printout will be different. I have use GDB and still cannot figure it out. Anyone know why the value of `correct_hash` can influence the final output?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned char correct_hash[20] = {
        0x30, 0x54, 0xcd, 0xb5, 0x14, 0x69, 0xa8, 0xfa, 0x4f, 0x9a,
        0x90, 0x11, 0xca, 0x62, 0x90, 0x56, 0xd7, 0xcd, 0xc1, 0x2f};

    unsigned char salt[8] = {0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42};
    unsigned char password[20] = {
        0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41,
        0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41};
    unsigned char salted_password[28];

    memcpy(salted_password, salt, 8);
    memcpy(salted_password+8, password, 20);
    SHA1(salted_password, strlen((char *)salted_password), password);
    printf("%s",password);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `strlen` on data which is not a (nul terminated) c style string.

Comment: Same provlem with printing: You mustn't provide a pointer to `printf` that does not point to a nul terminated string. Changes are high that you print whatever is in memory next to `password` which may include `salt`, `correct_hash` and other variables on stack

Comment: [openssl SHA1](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SHA1.html) provides the concise usage for that (and all) SHAxx functions.

Answer (score 1):

`salted_password` is binary data, not a string.  You can not use

```
strlen((char *)salted_password)
```

Answer (score 1):

`salted_password` and `password` are not null terminated strings so `printf()` and `strlen()` are unable to determine the correct length by searching for a (nonexistent in this case) null terminator character.

Try using `sizeof()` instead. I would also suggest using `sizeof()` instead of magic numbers.

```
memcpy(salted_password, salt, sizeof(salt));
memcpy(salted_password+sizeof(salt), password, sizeof(password));
SHA1(salted_password, sizeof(salted_password), password);
fwrite(password, sizeof(password), 1, stdout);
// fwrite() with sizeof() avoids undefined behavior but still might not print useful/readable data
```

Answer (score 1):

You invoke undefined behaviour in 2 places.

You mustn't pass a pointer to `strlen` that does not point to a valid nul-terminated string.
Your arrays are not strings.
If you do

```
SHA1(salted_password, strlen((char *)salted_password), password);
```

You will include anything that is in memory after `salted_password` until some 0 bytes is finally found.
It is very likely that the other arrays in your function will be included in calculating the hash.

Instead of `strlen` you need to use `sizeof` to get the size of your array.

Same limitation applies to printing a string using `printf("%s")`. You mustn't provide anything else than a pointer to a string.
Your array is likely to lack that nul-termination unless `SHA1` just by accident places one 0 byte into it.
The result is also likely to walk through all your neighboring arrays until a 0 byte is found.

Anyway, a hash is not necessarily a printable text. Instead you might better try to output hex values of the array content.